# How much do Android Developers make per download?

Tags: android, mobile, payment

I've recently completed an app for iOS. They flat out say you get 70% of the app sales. I'm thinking about developing for android as well. But I can't find anything on Android's sales. (Sorry it isn't exactly a programming question.)

Comment: Check [this out](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=112622&rd=1). You should also read [this](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html).

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. This is why you are getting downvotes and close requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 70% on Android also.

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=112622